# how to bind the 'text' datatype result set in an ajax call with json?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm looking for solutions of this context.
I request an ajax call to grab four set of array values from the DB.

> Ajax Call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/process/loadContractTabs", 
    type: "GET",
    data:{
          id : id
         },
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          if(data['resident'].length > 0){
                 // do the actions here                                                                                                                                        
          }
          if(data['charge'].length > 0){
                 // do the actions here                                                                                            
          }
          if(data['amount'].length > 0){
                 // do the actions here                                                                                            
          }
          if(data['tenancy'].length > 0){
                 // do the actions here                                                                                            
          }
    },
    error: function (data) {
          alert("Error in internet Connection..!\n\nTry agains." + "-"+data);
          window.location.reload(true);
    }
```

> Controller Action

```
    public function loadContractTabs(){
        if(isset($this->registry->data['id'])){
            $process=new process();
            $data = array();
            $data['resident'] = $process->loadContractResidentTab($this->registry->data['id']);
            $data['charge'] = $process->loadContractChargeTab($this->registry->data['id']);
            $data['amount'] = $process->loadContractAmountTab($this->registry->data['id']);    
            $data['tenancy'] = $process->loadContractTenancyTab($this->registry->data['id']);
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
```

As i mentioned in controller action, I'm requesting these four set of arrays as json to the views.Except the **$data['tenancy']**, rest of array set grabed their values to view as expected json.

The **$data['tenancy']** array dealing with 'text' datatype values as following in the model class.

```
    public function loadContractTenancyTab($id){
        $sql = "SELECT cmctd.id,cmctd.description FROM `cms_mstr_contract_tenancy_detail` AS cmctd WHERE cmctd.contract_id=:id";
        $data ['id'] = array ($id, 'int' );
        parent::prepare ( $sql );
        parent::databind ( $data );
        $result = parent::execute ();
        return $result;
    }
```

[image]

How to overcome this issue to grab all set of values as json to the view? If no suggest your best solution to this context.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you do a var_dump of $result in your controller, i think you are returning an object rather then an array value

Comment: Yah it's giving an object with only resident,amount and charge values. If i uncomment the $data['tenancy'] ,it returns no any object

Comment: it returns no any object?

Comment: It returns an object if only comments the $data['tenancy'] array.